# I have a branchZ from where I created a branchA and from that branchA I created a branchB, can I make it so branchB comes from branchZ?

Tags: git, github, branch, git-branch, rebase

I currently have something like this:

```
a -- b                  <-- branchZ
      \
       d -- e           <-- branchA
             \
              f -- g    <-- branchB
```

and I want to have something like this:

```
       f -- g           <-- branchB
      /
a -- b                  <-- branchZ
      \
       d -- e           <-- branchA
```

Is this possible??

Comment: The paragraph before the bottom graph is confusing. If you merge `branchA` into `branchB` when you're in the state of the first graph nothing will happen. If you're simply asking how to go from first graph to second graph so you can merge only f and g into `branchZ`, then maybe just ask that: How to go from graph1 to graph2, and we can answer that.

Comment: edited, thanks! Thats actually what I want to do, go from graph1 to graph2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to accomplish this. Conceptually you are doing a hard reset of `branchB` to point to commit `b` and then cherry-picking commits `f` and `g`. So for example:

```
git switch branchB
git reset --hard b
git cherry-pick f
git cherry-pick g
```

There's a more efficient way using `cherry-pick` since you can use ranges if your commits are consecutive, which they are in this case. The trick for a range is that the first commit you specify is the parent of the first commit you wish to include, like this:

```
git switch branchB
git reset --hard b
git cherry-pick f~1..g
```

Note that `f~1` is the parent of `f`, which in this case is `e`, and also `branchA`, so any of those will work.

Finally, there's an advanced version of rebase which is perhaps the best option here, since it does everything the above commands do, but all in a single command:

```
git rebase f~1 branchB --onto b
```

In words that says, take all commits on `branchB` that aren't reachable by commit `f~1` and replay them, in order, onto commit `b`. In this case you'll be left with `branchB` checked out even if it wasn't when you started.

Note that branches are just pointers to commits making them interchangeable. It might be slightly easier to understand if we use branch names for the rebase instead of commits, so the equivalent rebase command would be:

```
git rebase branchA branchB --onto branchZ
```

In words that says, take all the commits on `branchB` that aren't reachable by `branchA` and replay them, one by one, onto `branchZ`.